How can return an array in C#
I want to create a program that enters the values of that array using getArray() function and displays the entered values of array by using a function named displayArray(). So for this I have to return the array from getarray() function and that returned array is to be used by the display array function to display the array values.
I have tried in Google but all of them is listing in some other language. I have also gone through some Youtube videos, but the result was not satisfactory.

What have you tried? What did you find? Will I get paid if I do your homework?
